# why the chart's view doesnt symetric?

Tags: php, html, web, charts

I'm really confused why my chart being like this. From up to down page, the chart moved to the left, then the chart is being truncated. why can it be like that? what should I do so that the chart can be symmetric and not being truncated?

Here is my bargraph.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Portfolio Item - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/portfolio-item.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sekolah Pascasarjana IPB - Pasca Dalam Angka</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Beranda</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Tentang</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Kontak</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>


      <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jenis Kelamin</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">

                  <!--lineChart-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Fakultas</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                  <!--mybarChart-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas2"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jumlah Pelamar Magister Berdasarkan IPK S1</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">   
                  <!--canvasRadar-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas3"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jumlah Pelamar Berdasarkan Status PT</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                  <!--pieChart-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas4"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jumlah Pelamar Berdasarkan Usia</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">   
                  <!--canvasRadar-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas5"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jumlah Pelamar Magister Berd Instansi</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                  <!--pieChart-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas6"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jumlah Pelamar Program Magister Per Tahun</center></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">   
                  <!--canvasRadar-->
                    <canvas id="mycanvas7"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>






    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

what should I do so that the chart cant be truncated? thankyou so much

Here is the picture of the graph
[image]]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I missed the "container" syntax.
so here is the answer

```
<div class="container>
 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><center>Jenis Kelamin</center></h2>
```